# How to become an expert at Cloud technologies like AWS,Openstack and etc.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am an aspiring engineer who wants to enter the Cloud arena.

I see a lot of technologies like AWS, OpenStack and etc.

AWS offers certifications for aspiring engineers like me,

but my question is even if I were to obtain these professional level certifications, how would I put this knowledge into use without practical experience of designing and orchestrating cloud environments?

Comment: The point of those certifications is "getting hands on experience".

Comment: Hands on experience is for using and learning about AWS, but one has to transform the knowledge into implementing use cases ( like designing solutions for a problem ), right ? How can I get that realtime exposure ?

Answer (score 2):

The *only* way to learn something is to play with it.

Think of something you'd like to create, then **try and do it!** AWS is very low-cost if you turn things off when you aren't using them.

Try this:

- Build a web server on **Amazon EC2** that allows users to upload pictures.
- Store the picture in **Amazon S3** and push a message with the filename into an **Amazon SQS** queue.
- Write a back-end process that regularly checks the queue, retrieves the picture, resizes it, stores it back in S3 then sends an email with the link to the user via **Amazon SES**.

That's exactly what I did when applying for a job at AWS. I built it the day before my interview, never having used these services before. It was a very fun day!

The documentation is out there, so start doing stuff!

P.S. Yes, I got the job.